# Bluetooth Pairing vs. Connection in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am building an iOS app that connects to a bluetooth unit and I'm noticing that once when it is "connected" I am able to use the delegate method `didDiscoverServices`; however, when I go through and actually "pair" the bluetooth unit (an alert box pops up and asks to allow unit to pair to phone), I am no longer able to use the `didDiscoverServices` method, or other methods associated with the `CBPeripheral`.

I get the "pairing" option when I call the `readValueForCharacteristic` method. It is then that I get the "pairing" request. After I pair, I am not able to explore the units characteristics or services.

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{

    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        NSLog(@"Discovered service %@", service.UUID);
        [services addObject:service.UUID];
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];

    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{

    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

        NSLog(@"Discovered characteristic:  %@", characteristic.UUID);
        NSLog(@"Discovered characteristic Properties:  %@", characteristic.service);

        [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }

}
```

Comment: You should complete the discovery of services and characteristics before attempting to read the characteristic

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe that solved my problem. Thanks! If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pairing is initiated when you read/write a characteristic that requires encryption.  The pairing process establishes a new connection using the newly exchanged keys, which interrupts the discovery process.

The solution is to complete the discovery of services and characteristics before attempting the read operation.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my issue. Unfortunately, there isn't much in the documentation that talks about this. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the Core Bluetooth programming guide is pretty light on detail in the pairing/encryption department